# Cannot use code block directly below list

Tags: bug

When writing a post with a code, it is not possible to use block code directly after a list.

- This is a list
- It contains some items
- It's goal is to show that I can't use code below

  This is a code sample that is not being parsed.

If I write anything

```
I can use code now.
```

- The only place I can't use code is right after a list.

  Like here, for instance

  This is also code that is not being parse

  This is code too.

This is normal text.

```
This is code.
```